# Java Reactor Mono<Tuple2>.zipWith(Mono<>) should return Mono<Tuple3>

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

Let's say I have the following flow

```
Mono.just("value 1")
    .zipWith(Mono.just("value 2")) 
       //Mono<Tuple2<String, String>>
    .zipWhen(TupleUtils.function((value1, value2) -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> createValue3(value1, value2)))) 
      //Mono<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, String>>
```

And just for understanding

```
private String createValue3(String value1, String value2) {
    return "value 3";
}
```

As a result, I have

```
Mono<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, String>>
```

but I need

```
Mono<Tuple3<String, String, String>>
```

To continue frow with

```
.map(TupleUtils.function((value1, value2, value3) -> ...))
```

Is there any good solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think there is a much better solution, especially if you need value1 AND value2 to obtain value3. `zip(pub1, pub2, pub3` would have been an option otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly solution

```
.map(tuple -> Tuples.of(tuple.getT1().getT1(), tuple.getT1().getT2(), tuple.getT2()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the problem, Im using this approach:

zipWith and zipWhen have an overloaded variants with combiner argument,
so using this combiner u can directly tell how to build your response

U can check the explanation here:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWhen-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Example:

```
     Mono<Tuple3<String, String, String>> aAndBAndC = Mono.just("a")
            .zipWhen(a -> Mono.just("b"))
            .zipWith(Mono.just("c"), (aAndB, c) -> Tuples.of(aAndB.getT1(), aAndB.getT2(), c));
```